# SQL 1toM join Query where criteria in Child isn't met are shown

Tags: sql, join

I have a one to many table where I want to run a query and show records only for those records where in the child table a certain field has a certain value as well as seeing all those in the parent table that do not have this value.

Example of the Tables:

```
 A (parent)            B (child)    
============    =============================
 id | name        pid | typeid |    phone
------------    -----------------------------
  1 | Alex         1  |   1    | 555-555-5555
  2 | Bill         1  |   2    | 555-555-5556
  3 | Cath         2  |   1    | 555-555-5557
  4 | Dale         3  |   1    | 555-555-5558       
  5 | Evan         3  |   2    | 555-555-5559
  6 | Steve        3  |   3    | 555-555-5561
  7 | Henry        4  |   1    | 555-555-5562
  8 | Paul         5  |   1    | 555-555-5563
                   6  |   1    | 555-555-5564
```

---

The result I'm hoping for is that I can get all those that have a phone number with the typeid of 2 as well as know which parents don't without having duplicate result in the child table. So the final desired output would be:

```
 Desired Output (parent joined child)    
==========================================
 id | name  | pid  | typeid |    phone
------------------------------------------
  1 | Alex  |   1  |   2    | 555-555-5556
  2 | Bill  | null |  null  |    null
  3 | Cath  |   3  |   2    | 555-555-5559
  4 | Dale  | null |  null  |    null
  5 | Evan  | null |  null  |    null
  6 | Steve | null |  null  |    null
  7 | Henry | null |  null  |    null
  8 | Paul  | null |  null  |    null
```

so far the query I've attempted looks like:

```
SELECT id,  name, pid, typeid, phone

FROM
        parent  LEFT OUTER JOIN  child
  ON   parent.id     =    child.pid
WHERE typeid = 2 or typeid is null
```

That will return a list where the id is 1,3,7,8  But since the id 2,4,5,6 already have an entry in the child table they don't evaluate to null since in theory they could be joined to a record, just not where typeid is 2.

```
 Current Output (parent joined child)    
==========================================
 id | name  |  pid | typeid |    phone
------------------------------------------
  1 | Alex  |   1  |   2    | 555-555-5556
  3 | Cath  |   3  |   2    | 555-555-5559
  7 | Henry | null |  null  |    null
  8 | Paul  | null |  null  |    null
```

I was thinking the alternatives would be to do a union table, however even then I'm not sure how to test a join where an element (typeid = 2) doesn't exist without making two entries for id 3 pop up as well. So I guess I'm searching for a way to group by, but being selective about the data in the child table that gets populated by the groupby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the type criteria into the join clause instead of the where clause.

```
SELECT id, name, pid, typeid, phone
FROM parent  LEFT OUTER JOIN  child
ON parent.id = child.pid and child.typeid = 2
```

This will select all the parents and left join children that meet your criteria.

Comment: You can do that??!! That's new to me, thanks for showing it to me. Hmm seems my particular flavor of SQL isn't liking that much (msaccess) I'm going to play around with this until I get it.

Comment: I'm picking it as the answer because since your posting I've seen countless examples. Unfortunately it seems that didn't work for me in MSaccess so I had to split it into two queries which sucks but when push comes to shove.